# How do I make VS2008 place double quotes around intellisense offerings

Tags: visual-studio-2008, double-quotes, html-editor

I am in the HTML editor (building an ASP.NET MVC view) and coding up HTML.

The editor is handy with intellisense for various attributes, but when I select whatever VS2008 offers, it never places double quotes around them, as HTML says you should.

For instance:

```
<head runat=
```

offers `server`, but when I select it, I get:

```
<head runat=server
```

instead of

```
<head runat="server"
```

Is this a setting somewhere?

Comment: ReSharper, ReSharper, ReSharper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a setting, but if you start with a single quote, it will close it for you.

In HTML, you don't *have* to quote attributes.

In XHTML, you do.

Regardless, in the options you can set this:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Insert attribute value quotes when typing